# Html table with first column of fixed size and remaining columns equal size

Tags: html, css, html-table

The table I have has one header column and remaining data columns. 
I wish to have the following:

- the table takes 100% of the screen width.
- the first column has a fixed width of 150px.
- Remaining columns to have widths divided equally.
  I had posted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0ofgewz2/)

  ```css
  #my-table{width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;} /*or whatever width you want*/
  #my-table td{width:2000px;padding:4px;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:top;} /*something big or 100%*/
  #my-table td:first-child {width:150px;padding:4px;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:top;}
  ```

  ```html
  <table id="my-table"><tr>
      <td> CELL 1 Whith a lot of text in it</td>
      <td> CELL 2 </td>
      <td> CELL 3 </td>
      <td> CELL 4 Whith a lot of text in it </td>
      <td> CELL 5 </td>
      </tr></table>
  ```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to assign the following per td tag.

This way you can specify which column gets more space.

```
<td style="width:60%">... </td>
<td style="width:150px">... </td>
```

The browser will take care of the rest.

To force your width you can use

```
<td style="width: calc((100% - 150px)/5)">... </td> <!-- width is on fifth of remaining area -->
```

Please note that there are other solutions like css grid.

Answer (score 0):

You should use th for the header cells:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For the css:

```
table {
    width:100%;
}
th {
    width:150px;
} 
td {
   width: auto;
}
```

You can also omit the css for td, because 'width' is 'auto' by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'table-layout:fixed;' to #my-table and set the width of the first column with style attribute or through a css property.

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 150px;"> CELL 1 Whith a lot of text in it</td>
        <td> CELL 2 </td>
        <td> CELL 3 </td>
        <td> CELL 4 Whith a lot of text in it </td>
        <td> CELL 5 </td>
   </tr>
</table>

#my-table {
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#my-table td {
  padding:4px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```